# Generate dictionary by template in inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

At the moment I have the following inventory (simplified):

```yaml
children:
    child-1111:
        param: some-data-1111
    child-1112:
        param: some-data-1112
    child-1113:
        param: some-data-1113
```

Of course, it's not good when you need a thousand hosts instead of just three and many parameters with substitutions. I would like to write something like this (which doesn't work):

```yaml
children:
    "child-{{item}}":
        param: "some-data-{{item}}"
        loop:
            - 1111
            - 1112
            - 1113
```

All the examples I see always produce lists, not dictionaries.
Also, `loop` seems to work only for tasks, not inventories.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain the reason why you are looking to do such a thing? As, more usual approach to achieve this is using the [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) module to create dynamic inventory.

Answer (score 1):

Some forenotes:

- Your question is not very precise. My example will only give a general approach which is a bit more scalable than yours but will hit limits very soon.
- Your example is not a valid yaml inventory. Moreover it is not clear if you use the name `children` to declare children groups for the default `all` or if you want to use this as a group name (which I strongly suggest you **don't** do).
- Having to declare host specific variables depending on the host name inside a static inventory for loads of hosts is generally a sign of either a bad design or that you should switch to a fully [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) or by managing the hosts in your playbook dynamically through `add_host` (see @β.εηοιτ.βε's answer)

My example below declares a [range of hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-ranges-of-hosts) in a group named `my_children` and takes advantage of the host naming convention to capture their number and reuse it in a variable declared for the group

**`inv.yml`**

```yaml
---
my_children:
  vars:
    param: "some-data-{{ inventory_hostname.split('-')[1] }}"
  hosts:
    child-[1111:1113]:
```

You can see the hosts are parsed correctly:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i inv.yml --list
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "child-1111": {
                "param": "some-data-{{ inventory_hostname.split('-')[1] }}"
            },
            "child-1112": {
                "param": "some-data-{{ inventory_hostname.split('-')[1] }}"
            },
            "child-1113": {
                "param": "some-data-{{ inventory_hostname.split('-')[1] }}"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "my_children",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "my_children": {
        "hosts": [
            "child-1111",
            "child-1112",
            "child-1113"
        ]
    }
}
```

And the vars are interpreted correctly:

```
$ ansible my_children -i inv.yml -m debug -a "msg={{ param }}"
child-1111 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "some-data-1111"
}
child-1112 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "some-data-1112"
}
child-1113 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "some-data-1113"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those kind of requirements tend to be managed with the [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) module.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "child-{{ item.name }}"
        param: "some-data-{{ item.param }}"
        group: dynamic_hosts
      loop: "{{ _hosts }}"
      vars:
        _hosts:
          - name: 1111
            param: 1111-bis
          - name: 1112
            param: 1112-bis
          - name: 1113
            param: 1113-bis

- hosts: dynamic_hosts
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "On host `{{ item }}` the value of `param` is `{{ hostvars[item].param }}`"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      run_once: true
```

We are constructing a dynamic inventory group named `dynamic_hosts`, which we can then use in the same playbook.

This would actually yields:

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************

TASK [add_host] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 1111, 'param': '1111-bis'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 1112, 'param': '1112-bis'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 1113, 'param': '1113-bis'})

PLAY [dynamic_hosts] ************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [child-1111] => (item=child-1111) => 
  msg: On host `child-1111` the value of `param` is `some-data-1111-bis`
ok: [child-1111] => (item=child-1112) => 
  msg: On host `child-1112` the value of `param` is `some-data-1112-bis`
ok: [child-1111] => (item=child-1113) => 
  msg: On host `child-1113` the value of `param` is `some-data-1113-bis`
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Need a thousand hosts (.e.g. 'child-1111' param: 'some-data-1111')**"*

A: Use [*ranges*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-ranges-of-hosts) and [*constructed*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html#using-inventory-plugins) plugin. For example

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
child-[1111:1113]
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml
plugin: constructed
strict: True
groups:
  group_children: inventory_hostname.startswith('child-')
compose:
  param: "'some-data-' ~ inventory_hostname|split('-')|last"
```

Test it

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    group_children:
      hosts:
        child-1111:
          param: some-data-1111
        child-1112:
          param: some-data-1112
        child-1113:
          param: some-data-1113
    ungrouped: {}
```

and use it in a playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: param
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [child-1111] => 
  param: some-data-1111
ok: [child-1112] => 
  param: some-data-1112
ok: [child-1113] => 
  param: some-data-1113
```